# Derivative problem from khanacademy.com

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

The problem I found on the site was:

> Let $h(x) = 4\sqrt[4]{x^5}$. Find $h'(x)$.

I got the answer $h'(x) = \frac{5x^4}{\sqrt[4]{x^{15}}}$ and the site told me it was the correct answer. However, when I looked at what the correct answer was it told me it was $5x^\frac{1}{4}$. Therefore, I would assume that $\frac{5x^4}{\sqrt[4]{x^{15}}} = 5x^\frac{1}{4}$, but I don't understand how? The only simplification I could determine is $\frac{5x^4}{x^{\frac{15}{4}}}$. Can somebody show me the step by step simplification to get from my answer to their answer?

Comment: is this $h(x)=4\sqrt[4]{x^5}$?

Comment: Since you're studying calculus then surely you must know that $\dfrac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b}$ for nonzero $x$.  What's $4 - \dfrac{15}4$?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, yes

Comment: @tilper, I didn't know that or must be forgot, thank you, now everything make perfectly sense)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $h(x) = 4x^{5/4}$ so that

$$
h'(x) = 4\cdot \frac{5}{4}\cdot x^{5/4-1} = 5x^{1/4}
$$

---

*EDIT*: By using the chain rule:

$$
h'(x) = \frac{4}{4\sqrt[4]{x^{5\cdot 3}}}\frac{d (x^5)}{dx} = 5 \frac{x^4}{\sqrt[4]{x^{15}}} = 5 \frac{x^4}{x^{15/4}} = 5x^{4-15/4}=5x^{1/4}
$$

Comment: I solve with chain rule and that why get more complex answer)

Comment: @RamzanChasygov I updated my answer, hopefully it makes more sense now